# Windows Forms ToolTip will not re-appear after first use

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I have a Windows Forms C# application where I would like to use a tooltip on one of the text boxes. I initialize the tool-tip in the constructor of the Form class, and it works the first time. So when I hover over the text box with my mouse it works, but once the toolTip times out and it goes away, it does not re-appear when I move my mouse away and back onto the control. I would expect it to come back. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I initialize the tooltip:

```
myTip = new ToolTip();
myTip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
myTip.IsBalloon = true;
myTip.ShowAlways = true;

myTip.SetToolTip(txtMyTextBox,"My Tooltip Text");
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had a similar problem today. Sometimes, the tooltip would not show. I had one ToolTip control for all the controls in my form.

I also had a MouseEnter event on all the controls added automatically, so I modified the MouseEnter event to do:

```
_tooltip.Active = false;
_tooltip.Active = true;
```

It fixed the bug, but I don't know why.

Also, the bug always happened on Windows XP machines, but not on Windows Vista.

Comment: Yes - I too have this problem on XP machines but not Vista

Comment: This works perfectly. In order to avoid manual event hooking, you can use code such as foreach (var label in Control.Controls.OfType<Label>()) label.MouseEnter += (s, ea) =>
                    {
                        Main_Tooltip.Active = false;
                        Main_Tooltip.Active = true;
                    }; Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788490/c-how-can-i-iterate-through-all-checkboxes-on-a-form/1788757#1788757

Comment: I use tooltip in the context of DirectX9 app under XP,seems doen't work in this special situation.

Comment: While I wish I never had to fix framework bugs, I appreciate such simple and easy fixes as this one when i do. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I guess you'll be happy to know that Microsoft knows about it...since about 5 years...

- 2/21/2005   Bug acknowledged as reproducable
- 3/29/2005   Hum we might fix it, but later...
- 11/15/2005  Well actually it's not a big bug, and it doesn't happen much, so we won't fix it.

Damn I love it when I stumble on bugs Microsoft doesn't want to solve! This time it's called a *corner case*, last time it was simply *too difficult to resolve*...

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115385/tooltip-stop-showing-after-autopopdelay

I'm off to tell my client that the bugs in my program are just corner cases and too difficult to resolve...

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem today. VS 2010 SP1 .Net 3.5
After AutoPopDelay-Time the ToolTip do not show the Controls `ToolTipText`.
Kevins solution is the only way to solve the problem.

I encapsulate this in my own ToolTip class:

```
public class ToolTip : System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip 
{
    public ToolTip() : base() { }

    public ToolTip(System.ComponentModel.IContainer components) : base(components) { }

    public new void SetToolTip(System.Windows.Forms.Control ctl, string caption) 
    {
        ctl.MouseEnter -= new System.EventHandler(toolTip_MouseEnter);
        base.SetToolTip(ctl, caption);
        if(caption != string.Empty)
        ctl.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(toolTip_MouseEnter);
    }

    private void toolTip_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        this.Active = false;
        this.Active = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue in VB.NET. What I did was drop a TooTip control on the form, and then on the target control's MouseHover event, I set the properties of the ToolTip. I did this because I used one ToolTip control for five different Label controls. It worked great. (Really, I wanted the ToolTip to show immediately, so I used the MouseEnter event instead.) I can post my exact code tomorrow when I get to work.

Comment: Actually I figured it out on my own, but I used your Idea.

Comment: This helped me out wrote a program on windows 7 and tried to run my tooltips on windows xp. After rebuilding my app with your tip it works just great. THX

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I was having this problem on my Windows XP system until I noticed that if I placed at least one tooltip control on my form manually (from the toolbox) I could create as many tooltips as needed within my code, and they would all work.

If, however, I tried to create all tooltips in code (say for instance in the formload event) the tips would only show once and never to be seen again. I can't give you the exact "why this happens" story, but I have duplicated this issue several times always with the same effect. It might have something to do with the object scope, but I'm not sure.

So now just as a habit, I always include at least one Visual Studio tooltip control and then the rest within my code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by this

```
if (t == null)
{
    t = new ToolTip();
}
t.IsBalloon = true;
t.ToolTipTitle = "Stop";
t.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
t.Show("", yourControlonWhichToApplyToolTip, 0);

t.Show("PDescription", yourControlonWhichToApplyToolTip, 1000);
```

Note i have added an empty tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the the problem on Windows 7 so I found this thread.

In my case this did not work in tooltip_MouseEnter:

```
tooltip.Active = false;
tooltip.Active = true;
```

So I tried the following:

```
this.toolTip.SetToolTip(this.txtbx1, "tooltip-text");
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after setting the tooltip text with the `SetToolTip` method, I used the `Show` overload with `duration` parameter, i.e.

```
toolTip.Show(text, textEdit, 1000);
```

After that tooltip did not reappear on mouse hover, and resetting `tooltip.Active` didn't work..

A workaround that worked for me was to use `Show` overload without the duration, and hide it manually afterwards:

```
toolTip.Show(text, textEdit);
new Task(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(750);
    textEdit.Invoke(new Action(() => toolTip.Hide(textEdit)));
}).Start();
```

With this code I have the desired behaviour, i.e.

1. The tooltip is shown at once for 750 millisec. after the tooltip text has changed
2. The tooltip does appear for the specified time when the mouse is over the control

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();

private void textBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip1.Show("YOUR TEXT", textBox);
}

private void textBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip1.Active = false;
    ToolTip1.Active = true;
}
```