# WinForms: Why does my tooltip never come back?

Tags: winforms, tooltip

I'm having a problem getting the tooltip on my form. Once it disappears it never seems to come back!

Excerpt from the InitializeComponent method:

```
// 
// toolTip
// 
this.toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 60000;
this.toolTip.InitialDelay = 500;
this.toolTip.ReshowDelay = 100;
```

After the InitializeComponent method has been called:

```
toolTip.SetToolTip(control1, "text");
```

Firstly, if I hover over the control1 control I see "text" in a tooltip for 5 seconds, regardless of what I set the AutoPopDelay to. I've even tried setting it to Int32.MaxValue.

Secondly, if I let the pop up show for 5 seconds, after it disappears it never come back. If I move the mouse or something before 5 seconds has passed the tooltip will come back as expected if I hover over the control again.

Has anyone had and solved these issues before? I don't seem to be able to find an answer to this specific problem online.

TIA

Comment: This is a WinForms application.

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559707/c-tooltip-will-not-re-appear-after-first-use also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254656/tooltips-with-infinite-timeout/2438612#2438612

Answer (score 2):

About the delay time:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.autopopdelay.aspx

> The maximum time you can delay a popup
>   is 5000 milliseconds. For longer
>   durations, use the Show method to
>   control the exact moment when the
>   ToolTip is displayed.

Comment: There is still the problem of the tooltip now showing again tho - I'm experiencing the same issue :/

Comment: MSDN is a bit misleading in this case. I set AutoPopDelay to 30000 and it works well. The limitation is actually ~32 seconds. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254656/tooltips-with-infinite-timeout/2438612#2438612