# How can I iterate through all checkboxes on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a form that has many dynamically generated checkboxes. At runtime, how can I iterate through each of them so I can get their value and IDs?

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Forms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is CheckBox)
   {
   // Do stuff here ;]
   }
}
```

Comment: Does not work if the controls are embedded inside other controls. "this" is not everything.

Comment: Yes @Fernando68 you would have to create a recurrent function that goes through all the 'children'. 

This is an answer from almost 8 years ago :D

Comment: @AllanRamirez this answer is almost 9 years old :)

Comment: @MichalFranc Hi, I know, but I found the solution.

Comment: @AllanRamirez Awesome!

Answer (score 19):

I use a simple extension method that will work for any control type:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> AllControls<T>(this Control startingPoint) where T : Control
  {
     bool hit = startingPoint is T;
     if (hit)
     {
        yield return startingPoint as T;
     }
     foreach (var child in startingPoint.Controls.Cast<Control>())
     {
        foreach (var item in AllControls<T>(child))
        {
           yield return item;
        }
     }
  }
```

Then, you can use it like so:

```
var checkboxes = control.AllControls<CheckBox>();
```

Using IEnumerable lets you choose how to store the results, and also lets you use linq:

```
var checkedBoxes = control.AllControls<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked);
```

Comment: +1 they can be nested, good point, and using lambdas is always a plus )

Comment: This is probably more useful than Control.Controls

Comment: This is definitly best and most elegant ansawer! Good job.

Answer (score 12):

If it is [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), you can try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, bool> checkBoxes = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    LoopControls(checkBoxes, this.Controls);
}

private void LoopControls(Dictionary<string, bool> checkBoxes, Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox)
            checkBoxes.Add(control.Name, ((CheckBox) control).Checked);
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            LoopControls(checkBoxes, control.Controls);
    }
}
```

Remember that container controls can contain children, so you might want to check those too.

Answer (score 9):

Like this, maybe (if it's in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)):

```
foreach(var checkBox in myForm.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{   
   //Do something.
}
```

Comment: I've been doing just this for a while - provided I know there's no nesting in containers. You might mention that your solution also allows a .Where(c=>c.Checked) (or other Linq expression) to be appended for the unaware.

Answer (score 1):

When they are created, get a list of references to the values, and then you can iterate over the list.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is old, but It was easy as I can imagine.

Just add all checkboxes into a `List<Checkbox>`, all checkboxes state are in the list and even if they change in the UI in the list changes too.

```
List<Checkbox> checkboxes = new List<Checkboxes>();
checkboxes.Add(chk1);
checkboxes.Add(chk2);
//So add all checkboxes you wanna iterate

foreach(Checkbox checkbox in checkboxes){
    //Do something using checkbox object
}
```

Hope this helps :)