# determining the type of control in Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How can you determine the type of control in `Request.Form`?

```
 foreach (string x in Request.Form.Keys)
 {                                
    if (Request.Form[x] == null || Request.Form[x].ToString() == "")
    {....
```

I would like to know for each loop, what is the type of control.

Is it a textbox, a listbox, a hidden field etc...

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to know it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788490/c-how-can-i-iterate-through-all-checkboxes-on-a-form

Comment: @corn3lius: I don't see how that is related to this question. OP wants the control type of every `Request.Form.Key`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's related because one of the most common reasons for wanting to know is to filter on it.  And it's appropriate because it's a comment, not an answer, so being related yet not an exact duplicate is appropriate.

Comment: it's a litle bit complicated, I use asp.net MVC 2 that post on a ASP.NET WebForm application. For that reason, It's seem I can't use  foreach (Control in this.Controls) ... This is Why I wanted to do that with Request.Form. . Please how can I get the control type based on the Request.Form method. Any Idea. And Why Down Voting my question ?

Answer (score 1):

Once in a great while it is useful to manually work with the Request collection rather than with strongly typed control objects. However, iterating through all controls is probably a bad idea in almost any case.

You could perform a [recursive](http://sharpertutorials.com/recursive-findcontrol/) `FindControl()` using the keys in the Request collection. If `FindControl` doesn't return null, check the type of control.

Note that the key submitted is different than the actual ID of the control. It usually looks something like:

```
<input type="text" name="foo$bar$txtFirstName" id="foo_bar_txtFirstName" />
```

"name" is the actual key in the Request collection but "id" is the ID of the control. This necessitates further a further mapping step.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The browser does not submit this information. The HTTP standard does not contain a way to transmit this information intrinsically.