# Determine if no Radio Button is Checked

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

A large group of radio buttons exist on a form. They are not inside a panel, but for this example they are the only set of radios on the form.

At initialization, **no** button will be selected.  (Likely, this is  not proper implementation of radios, but it's outside of my control; Suffice to say, for this example, the form must start out with no radio button selected.)

Currently I use a rather lengthy if-else statement to check each button one at a time, but I feel there must be a simpler way to determine, right off the bat, if no button is checked. Besides the buttons already work as a group, because by definition a maximum of 1 selection is forced throughout.

What would be the best practice for detecting if **no radio button** has been selected?

Comment: If they really are **radio buttons**, one of them should *always* be selected, and there should be a property in the Option Group that tells you *which* one is selected.

Comment: @RobertHarvey not on initialization. On initialization, they are all "off"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788490/c-how-can-i-iterate-through-all-checkboxes-on-a-form

Comment: Then set a default one on during initialization.  Radio buttons are not intended to be all unchecked.

Comment: What do you mean by *the most efficient way?*

Comment: The first answer in the linked question answers your question.  Check for a `null` return value.

Comment: @Robert Harvey In this specific case, I'm intending to start blank, for example, on initialization of the form, (They will remain blank until user input because selecting one of them causes a large load of data) - Can this Option Group property determine that no button has been selected?

Comment: Yes, look at the linq statement in that answer.  It should return `null` if none of the radio buttons are selected.

Comment: I cannot confirm yet that the above example worked for my code, although it may have been an error on my implementation.  I did have successful use of itsme86's suggestion, though, so I'm not pursuing further.

Comment: @L.B For future refference, L.B, "most efficient" in general reffers to the option with the most preferable ratio of manual work vs. resource-usage, while still producing a virtually-identical result to common alternatives.  (My bad, I shouldn't have assumed  the definition was common-knowledge.)

Comment: @Doc, Yes your bad. My definition includes speed, memory usage, parallelism etc.

Comment: @L.B In this case, which of the given answers would your definition prove to be the most efficient?  I'm always looking for ways to practice more pragmatism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always create a collection of the radio buttons:

```
RadioButton[] radioButtons = new RadioButton[] { radioButton1, radioButton2 };

if (!radioButtons.Any(rb => rb.Checked))
    // No radio buttons are checked
```

Also, using this similar question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked)) as a reference, you could do something like:

```
if(!Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(rb => rb.Checked))
    // No radio buttons are checked
```

Comment: I get "no definition" on the use of the word "any"

Comment: @DanCundy You might be targeting .NET framework 2.0 or earlier. You need 3.5 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

I would would guess something like this:

```
form.Controls.Where(x => x is RadioButton).Where(x => x.Selected == true).Count()
```

Or if you have them available in an array or list of some sort you don't have to loop all the controls.

I suppose you could speed it up a bit by:

```
form.Controls.Where(x => x is RadioButton && ((RadioButton)x).Selected == true).Count()
```

Comment: Oh yeah.. off course, It's probably better doing it as @itsme86 says. Just forgot about "Any". =)

Comment: was missing the system.lync directive.