# Count the number of controls - C# with the certain names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, controls, c#-2.0

C# - 2.0

I am trying to figure out on how to do a loop on a list of controls with certain names: "txtTesting[i]"

> ```
> txtTesting1
> txtTesting2
> txtTesting3 ...
> txtTesting13
> ```

With the code I have a total of 13.  But this can change as time goes by.  So I am looking to get the data from the textboxes that have data in them.  I just can not seem to figure out a way to do a count of the controls.  I have tried this...

```
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (txtTesting[i].text != "")
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I am also getting this error... 
`Error 51 The name 'txtTesting' does not exist in the current context`

Unless I am missing something here.

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`

Comment: Nope.  But you could just throw all the controls in a collection and loop through that.

Comment: hmmm. not sure on how I could do that.

Comment: Is this a Windows or ASP.NET app?

Comment: If windows is it winform or wpf?  I assume winforms if this is C# 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a `System.Windows.Forms` application, you should be able to go through all your controls on the form and then select the ones that are TextBox as follows:

```
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
            {
                if (((System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)control).Text != "")
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        }
```

For an asp.net application this would be very similar:

```
        foreach (System.Web.UI.Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
            {
                if ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)control).Text != "")
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`txtTesting` looks like an array.  does it have a `Length` property?

```
for (int i = 1; i < txtTesting.Length; i++)
```

if it's a type `List<T>` than maybe it has a `Count` property

```
for (int i = 1; i < txtTesting.Count; i++)
```

If you don't already have an array, you can initialize one in your presumed Form's constructor

```
List<WhateverTypeTxtTestingIs> txtTesting = new List<WhateverTypeTxtTestingIs>();

txtTesting.Add(txtTesting1);
txtTesting.Add(txtTesting2);
...
```

Comment: Nah.  I think he's saying that he has "txtTesting1", "txtTesting2", each one a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach over your array:

```
    foreach (TextBox txt in txtTesting)
    {
        if (txt.text != "")
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Or, the array has a length property that you can use.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < txtTesting.length; i++)
    {
        if (txtTesting[i].text != "")
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

If you don't have an array of controls, you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788538/787893) to loop through all the controls on your form.  Except the generic Dictionary isn't in C# 2, so it will look more like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList txtTesting = ArrayList();
    LoopControls(controls, this.Controls);
    foreach (TextBox txt in txtTesting)
    {
        if (txt.text != "")
        {
            //
        }
    }
}

private void LoopControls(ArrayList list, Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox && control.Name.StartsWith("txtTesting"))
            list.Add(control);
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            LoopControls(list, control.Controls);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *most* efficient way would be to add the controls to an array and loop over that, but you could also loop through the controls and inspect the control's `Name`:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)  // <-- "this" may not be appropriate - you just need to reference the containing control
{
   if(c.Name.StartsWith("txtTesting")
   {
      ///
   }
}
```

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Comment: I assumed windows since you didn't specify.  Use `ID` instead of `Name`

Comment: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, after the call to InitializeComponent, stuff the text boxes in a collection.

```
// class-scoped variable
private List<Textbox> _boxen = new List<TextBox>();

public MyFormDerp()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _boxen.Add(txtTesting1);
    // etc
    _boxen.Add(txtTesting13);
}
```

and, later on...

```
foreach(TextBox box in _boxen)
    if (box.text != "")
    {
        //
    }
```

Also, your design should make you itch.

Comment: Also also 2.0?  Jeez.