# Loop c# - use variable in textbox

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

I made a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sumUSERS; i++ )
{

principal.UserPrincipalName = "bn" + txtbox_cusnumber.Text + "." + txt_user1.Text;

}
```

In my Form i have Text boxes with the following names :

- txt_user1
- txt_user2
- txt_user3

How can I set the value i in `txt_user(i).text`?

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Its not possible like that. you have to loop over all controls and check if that is Text Box. an example for looping over Checkbox : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788490/how-can-i-iterate-through-all-checkboxes-on-a-form

Comment: You can find controls within a container by name like this `#MyContainer.Controls.Find("myControlName", true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of the boxes, and use an index, like this:

```
var txt_user = new [] {txt_user1, txt_user2, txt_user3};
for (int i = 0; i < txt_user.Length ; i++ ) {
    principal.UserPrincipalName += "bn" + txtbox_cusnumber.Text + "." + txt_user[i].Text;
}
```

Note that I replaced `=` with `+=`, otherwise the text would be the same as if you used `txt_user3` by itself (i.e. only the last assignment would stay).