# Installing software programmatically using powershell

Tags: powershell

** Updated Code I have listed now works!!  **

I built a form with checkboxes programmatically that's pulling from a csv file and it works but I've been racking my head for a but on how to get it to install everything that is checked programmatically. so say if FileZilla is checked then it'll grab the path that's listed in the csv. If it's not checked then it'll move on to say Firefox and if its checked it'll grab the path to install it. so and so on. There's not a lot I've been able to find and I'm hoping someone here has run across this! here's my code :

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,700) 
$Form.text ="Software Installer" 

############################################## Start group boxes

$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)  
$groupBox.text = "Availabe Software to Install:" 
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)


$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "Install"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(230,30)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'



$apps = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Name = ''

    Path = ''

    PreTransfer = ''

}


$apps = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\applist.csv


$groupBox.Controls.Add($Button1)

$Checkboxes = @()
$y = 20
foreach ($a in $apps)
{    
    $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkbox.name = $a.Name
    $Checkbox.Text = $a.Name
    $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$y) 
    $y += 30
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Checkbox) 
    
    $Checkboxes += $Checkbox

}


$groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,(40*$checkboxes.Count)) 


 //what I was trying to get to look at each box but couldn't figure it out.
$Button1.Add_Click({ foreach ($i in $Checkboxes){
    if ($i.checked -eq $true) {
    Start-Process $i.AccessibleDescription
    }
}
 })

$form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Comment: Once you've obtained the path to the relevant installer, you could then make a call to [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) passing the path to the installer and specifying any arguments required for performing an unattended or silent install?

Comment: How would I be able to call the path though based on which boxes are checked since the checkboxes are being made from the csv. It makes sense if I was making a static form cause I could call the button .add_click for each checkbox but since the boxes are generated each time the script runs I don't know how to call the path or run the path if the box is checked.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788505/10601203) is an example of looping through all checkboxes (it's in C# so same thing just slightly different syntax). As for actually installing the software, not every software uses the same installation method. A lot use MSI installers which are pretty easy, but there are a handful that use custom installers with custom arguments. However in my case I needed to do them all silently which might not be a requirement in your case. If it's not, you can simply start the process. If it is, you need to use different arguments for each custom installer.

Comment: Ya I dont need it to install it I just need it to start the process some of them are silent installers. Some of them are either ps1 scripts, bat, or exe. I just need it to run/start the process!

Comment: It has nothing to do with powershell; each installer has unique silent install options like "/S".  Some of them run in the background and some don't.  If it's an msi, you can use install-package if there's no unusual options.

Comment: Got it working with this! $Button1.Add_Click({ foreach ($i in $Checkboxes){
    if ($i.checked -eq $true) {
    Start-Process $i.AccessibleDescription
    }
}
 })

Answer (score 0):

Doing this works

```
$Button1.Add_Click({
    foreach ($i in $Checkboxes){
    if ($i.checked -eq $true) {
    Start-Process $i.AccessibleDescription
    }
}
 })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).