# What causes the .NET ToolTip not to work a second time?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, tooltip

Using VB.NET 2008 desktop project, I created a simple tooltip on `Form_Load` event and attached it to a button on the form. Looks great when user hovers over button but times out after 30 seconds (which I set using popup delay etc.). But once it fades out, the second time user hovers over the button, the tooltip never shows up.  Almost like it dies a natural death! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms ToolTip will not re-appear after first use.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559707/winforms-tooltip-will-not-re-appear-after-first-use) Have you tried the solutions proposed in answer to that question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the [`ToolTip` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) will not show the tip a second time if the first tip timed out. 
I suppose this is a "feature" not a bug, but I agree it's not the expected behavior for many people. It has been [reported to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115385/tooltip-stop-showing-after-autopopdelay), who feel it is "too much of a corner case to invest fixing it".

The answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559707/winforms-tooltip-will-not-re-appear-after-first-use) propose some possible workarounds, although I haven't personally tried any of them because I've never needed a tooltip that displayed for so long that it timed out.

The first workaround I would suggest that you try is what Kevin's answer proposes: Set the `ToolTip` component's `Active` property to False, and then back to True in the `MouseEnter` event for each control that you want to display said tooltip. This will basically "reboot" the component and override the "feature" that causes it not to show a second time once it's timed out the first time.

Some of the other suggestions that are proposed in the answers achieve the same result a slightly different (and more inane) way: by creating a *new* `ToolTip` component each time that the user moves the mouse over the control. There's really no reason this is better, or that it will work when the above suggestion won't.

As for why the tooltip times out after only 30 seconds, well the actual maximum timeout is something like 32 seconds. The component provided by the .NET Framework is simply a wrapper for the Win32 ToolTip, which the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760250(v=vs.85).aspx) reveals as the source of the seemingly arbitrary limit. The time-out value is specified as a signed 16-bit value, which accepts a maximum value of only 32767, translating to a delay of just over 32 seconds. Raymond Chen also posted a [blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031110-00/?p=41903) about this exact behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mouseover event ( the lightning bolt icon under properties for, in this case, my textbox ) for your textbox or other control that you want to use and call your routine. I called mine reactivate_tooltip.

```
Private Sub reactivate_tooltip(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.MouseEnter
        ToolTip1.Active = False
        ToolTip1.Active = True
End Sub
```