# IsBalloon property makes Windows Forms ToolTip position inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

When I set the `IsBalloon` property of a `ToolTip` control, and then use the `ToolTip.Show()` method to display it, the balloon's tail doesn't always point at the location I request. It seems like the first time I call `Show()`, the tooltip control appears with its top-left corner in the location I requested, and the balloon tail pointing down. If I call `Show()` again before the tooltip fades, then it reappears in the position I asked for.

Is there some setting that will make the position more consistent? I'd like to keep the balloon style if possible.

Here's a code sample that will demonstrate the failure. I'm asking for it to point at the top-left corner of the text box.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    const int TIP_X = 50;
    const int TIP_Y = 100;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Show("Test", groupBox1, TIP_X, TIP_Y, 5000);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50);
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(TIP_X, TIP_Y);
        this.toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;

        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Button button1;
    private GroupBox groupBox1;
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private ToolTip toolTip1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to notify the user of something they might be interested in, but they can safely ignore it. I thought that a balloon notification would work well, since it can point to something specific in the user interface that I'm telling the user about.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, running on .NET 3.5 under Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, the best workaround I've found is to just call the `Show()` method twice:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Show("Test", groupBox1, TIP_X, TIP_Y, 5000);
        toolTip1.Show("Test", groupBox1, TIP_X, TIP_Y, 5000);
    }
```

Hopefully, there's something nicer than that.

Stack Overflow question *[Windows Forms ToolTip will not re-appear after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559707/)* sounds vaguely similar, and mentions [the bug *ToolTip balloon flickers position using Show method*](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483583/tooltip-balloon-flickers-position-using-show-method) that Microsoft doesn't seem interested in fixing.