# Tooltip in c# form does not appear when switching computers

Tags: c#

Hi I am having a very strange problem. I have a form with multiple tooltips that appear when the mouse is over a specific control. So far I was developing the form on a Windows 7 machine and everything were going fine. Tonight I tested my executable on my other Windows 7 machine (same version and service pack) but none of the tooltips are working.

Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem? Bellow I am giving the code for one such Tooltip

```
    ToolTip UrlNameInputBallonTip = new ToolTip();
    private void CheckForUrl()
    {
        UrlNameInputBallonTip.IsBalloon = true;
        if (IsValidHttpUri(UrlNameInput.Text) == false && IsValidHttpsUri(UrlNameInput.Text) == false)
        {
            UrlNameInputBallonTip.SetToolTip(UrlNameInput, "This is not a valid url!\r\nex. \"http://domain\"");
            UrlNameInputBallonTip.Show("This is not a valid url!\r\nex. \"http://domain\"", UrlNameInput, UrlNameInput.Width / 2, UrlNameInput.Height, 5000);
        }
        else
        {
            UrlNameInputBallonTip.Hide(this);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Is it the ToolTip or the IsValid function?

Comment: I have test is. Is not the valid function. The same code exactly runs on my developing machine but does not run on my other machine.

Comment: What I meant was, did you test to just show the ToolTip?  The posted code works, so the issue points to the IsValid functions.  Are the inputs the same, etc.

Comment: This is really strange. Other part of the code do not run well either. Could this be a problem with .net framework?

Comment: Hi LarsTech yes the inputs are the same. I have tested my code on a virtual machine running windows vista and .net framework 4.0 and it works ok. So far it is in just one machine that does not work. Any ideas? Should I reinstall .net framework or will that not help at all?

Comment: Create a new program that just shows the ToolTip.  See if that works on the machine in question.

Comment: Hi LarsTech I have created a very simple program just with the tooltip and it works OK! So do you have an idea how to start troubleshooting the problem on my main app?

Comment: Well, now you know the ToolTip probably isn't the issue.  Now add your IsValid functions to that new project, test that.

Comment: Hi LarsTech it is not the IsValid. I have created the following test code:

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }
        
        ToolTip UrlNameInputBallonTip = new ToolTip();

Comment: private void UrlNameInput_KeyUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
            UrlNameInputBallonTip.IsBalloon = true;
            UrlNameInputBallonTip.SetToolTip(UrlNameInput, "This is not a valid url!\r\nex. \"http://domain\"");
            UrlNameInputBallonTip.Show("This is not a valid url!\r\nex. \"http://domain\"", UrlNameInput, UrlNameInput.Width / 2, UrlNameInput.Height, 5000);
       
        }
    }
}

Comment: Although the MessageBox.show("Test") does come up the tooltip does not! Again in my developing machine works just great. Very strange. Any ideas please?

Comment: I was under the impression the ToolTip experiment was working on the suspect machine.  My only suggestion would be to play with the InitialDelay property.  Other than that, it's hard to help with so little to go on.

Comment: Yes if I put the lines of the tooltip  UrlNameInputBallonTip.IsBalloon = true;
UrlNameInputBallonTip.SetToolTip(UrlNameInput, "This is not a valid url!\r\nex. \"http://domain\"");
UrlNameInputBallonTip.Show("This is not a valid url!\r\nex. \"http://domain\"", UrlNameInput, UrlNameInput.Width/2, UrlNameInput.Height, 5000);
       in the Form_Load function the tooltip works. It is when I put them in the KeyUp event that does not. At first I though that the KeyUp event was not registering properly, but after putting the MessageBox I realize that it the KeyUp event it works!

Comment: Thanks LarsTech I understand. However my test app is pretty simple. For some reason on the suspected machine the tooltip does not fire when it is put in the KeyUp event although on my developer machine it works great. I am also very confused since I also do not know what to do next.

Comment: I manage to narrow it down. It seems that the problem is the line  UrlNameInputBallonTip.IsBalloon = true; If I remove this the tooltip do appear on the suspected machine. Although I do not understand why they don't when the above property is set to true.

Comment: Don't know.  Try [Windows Forms ToolTip will not re-appear after first use](http://stackoverflow.com/q/559707/719186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I was able to find the cause of the problem and I am reporting this for future reference. On the suspected machine the option to display balloon tips (arrow pointing to the control) was disabled. I am not sure why, perhaps some other app disable it at some point, but after enabling it through registry ti works fine now. Thanks for the help!