# WinForms: ToolTips will not (re)appear after the initial mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, sharpmap

I am working on a form that uses a SharpMap MapBox to display objects as points on a world map. Currently, if I enter the MapBox (mapBox1) with the cursor and stop on the point, it displays the tooltip as I want it to. However, once I've stopped the mouse within the MapBox (not necessarily on the point) and move the mouse within the MapBox, moving to the point will not (re)display the tooltip. However, if I leave the MapBox (say, moving the cursor out of the window or onto one of the menu strips, or onto a button overlaid on the map) I can then get the tooltip to appear, but only once before I have to move the cursor as before.

**What is causing this behaviour, and is there any easy way to fix it?**

I've tried using ToolTip.Hide(), ToolTip.Active = false (and then setting it to true again when I want it displayed) and refreshing the MapBox at various points.

Relevant code:

The ToolTip is global, and the constructor defines it as follows:

```
toolTip.InitialDelay = 1000;
toolTip.ReshowDelay = 750;
toolTip.ShowAlways = true;
```

I then have two event handlers for the mouse, both tied to the MapBox. "obj" is a global object of a custom class containing the latitude and longitude points.

```
private void mapBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PointF pos = mapBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        int screenToleranceX = 20, screenToleranceY = 20;
        PointF posLow = new PointF(pos.X - screenToleranceX, pos.Y - screenToleranceY);
        PointF posHigh = new PointF(pos.X + screenToleranceX, pos.Y + screenToleranceY);
        GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate objLoc = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(obj.longitude, obj.latitude);
        PointF objPoint = mapBox1.Map.WorldToImage(objLoc);
        if (posLow.X <= objPoint.X && objPoint.X <= posHigh.X && posLow.Y <= objPoint.Y && objPoint.Y <= posHigh.Y)
        {
            toolTip.Active = true;
            toolTip.Show(obj.Name, mapBox1, mapBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        }
    }

    private void mapBox1_MouseMove(GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate worldPos, MouseEventArgs imagePos)
    {
        PointF pos = mapBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        int screenToleranceX = 20, screenToleranceY = 20;
        PointF posLow = new PointF(pos.X - screenToleranceX, pos.Y - screenToleranceY);
        PointF posHigh = new PointF(pos.X + screenToleranceX, pos.Y + screenToleranceY);
        GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate objLoc = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(obj.longitude, obj.latitude);
        PointF objPoint = mapBox1.Map.WorldToImage(objLoc);
        if (toolTip.Active && (posLow.X > objPoint.X || objPoint.X > posHigh.X || posLow.Y > objPoint.Y || objPoint.Y > posHigh.Y))
        {
            toolTip.Active = false;
        }
    }
```

**** EDIT ****

As per the accepted answer, I have the following code as a solution, with hopes to refine it further as needed. This works for now, however (using an externally declared bool, toolTipDisp, defaulted to false):

```
private void mapBox1_MouseMove(GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate worldPos, MouseEventArgs imagePos)
    {
        PointF pos = mapBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        int screenToleranceX = 20, screenToleranceY = 20;
        PointF posLow = new PointF(pos.X - screenToleranceX, pos.Y - screenToleranceY);
        PointF posHigh = new PointF(pos.X + screenToleranceX, pos.Y + screenToleranceY);
        GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate objLoc = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(obj.longitude, obj.latitude);
        PointF objPoint = mapBox1.Map.WorldToImage(objLoc);
        if (posLow.X <= objPoint.X && objPoint.X <= posHigh.X && posLow.Y <= objPoint.Y && objPoint.Y <= posHigh.Y)
        {
            if (!toolTipDisp)
            {
                toolTip.Show(obj.Name, mapBox1, mapBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
                toolTipDisp = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            toolTip.Hide(mapBox1);
            toolTipDisp = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code.. I bet it's not working because you have an issue if `toolTip.Active = false;` have you looked at the documentation to see the order that event get triggered perhaps it's always .Active = false all the time.. what if you comment out the  `toolTip.Active = false;` do you get the expected behavior..??

Comment: Which OS? I remember when I switch from XP to 7, there were some problems with tooltip. Finally I ended up with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25074658/1997232). Setting tooltip will update it, but **only do** this if tooltip changes (or it will ugly flickers).

Comment: @Sinatr: I'm running Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Whenever I have stepped through it, I see that whenever the cursor stops in the correct position, it tries to show the ToolTip, as I would expect it to. If I don't use toolTip.Active = false, or try to hide the ToolTip, it persists until I change focus away from the form containing the MapBox, which is even less desirable. One possibility would be to make the tooltip expire after a few seconds, but I would rather it persist as, in the future, I may have more than one point sitting around and several may be in close proximity.

Comment: I don't know how `MapBox` is implemented, but lets assume it's a single control. Then [`MouseHover`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover.aspx) occurs *only once* and never again (until `MouseLeave`). Your best bet is to use only `MouseMove` to display/re-display tooltip. And this is what I told you earlier: in `MouseMove` event generate a text for tooltip. If text is different from what it was - display tooltip (by using `ToolTip.Show` method), otherwise do nothing. In `MouseLeave` hide tooltip (by using `ToolTip.Hide` method).

Comment: I'm not sure that will work exactly as you're describing it for what I'm trying to do, but it has given me an idea. I'll try it out, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (pseudo-code):

```
private string _previous;

private void mapBox1_MouseMove(GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate worldPos, MouseEventArgs imagePos)
{
    var text = ...; // generate tooltip text based on the new position
    if(text != _previous)
    {
        _previous = text;
        tooltip.Show(text, mapBox1, mapBox1.PointToClient(imagePos.Location)); 
    }
}

private void mapBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip.Hide(mapBox1);
}
```

Comment: This was close, but I am unable to use a MouseLeave event for my purposes. However, this did give me the idea for the solution I came up with, so I will mark it as the answer, and post my final solution as an edit.  
  
By using only the MouseMove event, and using the condition previously in the MouseHover event (and an else) I am able to display the tooltip when the mouse enters the bounding box of the point. However, this causes flickering of the tooltip. By using a boolean variable that is set true when the tooltip is displayed, and set false when it is hidden, the flicker is eliminated.