# Adding tool tip to dithered text box

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to add tool tip to a dithered textbox in winform. For adding the tooltip, mouse hover event is needed but in case of dithered text box, mouse hover event doesn't fire. Is there any other way to add tooltip for mouse hovering?

When the user hovers over this dithered textbox, the entire content of textbox should display in tooltip.

Comment: What do you mean by a dithered `TextBox`?

Comment: 'TextBox' which is not editable and on which control can't go. It basically behaves as a 'Label'.

Comment: Do you set `Enabled=false` or set`ReadOnly=true`?

Comment: Enabled is set to false and ReadOnly is set to true.

Comment: Set enabled to `true` and try [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37482628/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei If I set the enabled to 'true' , while tabbing the control would go this dithered textbox, right?

Comment: It's enough to set `TabStop` to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ToolTip doesn't show for TextBox the first time that mouse hovers on it.

It seems the tooltip for `TextBox` only appears on second hover event. It doesn't matter whether the `TextBox` is `ReadOnly` or not. But as a workaround, you can handle `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` events yourself and write such code:

```
private void textBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var point = this.textBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    point.Offset(0, 20);
    this.toolTip1.Show("Some Text", this.textBox1,
        point, 2000);
}
private void textBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.toolTip1.Hide(this.textBox1);
}
```

Here is the screenshot of behavior before fix:

[image]

Screenshot after fix:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about this? I don't have my VM with Visual Studio running at the moment, but surely I'd have noticed this bug before. If you create the ToolTIp control and associate it with the correct control in your form's constructor (SetToolTip), you still see this delay? There should be no reason to call the Show method manually. I've heard of the bug that [a tooltip won't reappear on subsequent invocations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559707/windows-forms-tooltip-will-not-re-appear-after-first-use), but not that it *only* appears on subsequent invocations.

Comment: @CodyGray **The first screenshot** is the normal behavior (maybe bug). I put a tooltip component on form and set tooltip for textboxes at design time. Then I run the code and you can see the result. The tooltip doesn't show on fisrt hover, it shows on second hover. I only use a single tooltip component. **About calling show manually** I also prefer to not call show manually, but after some try and error this was the best result that I could gain. **The current problem** is not about re-appearing, the problem event exists for first appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
        TextBox TB = (TextBox)sender;
        int VisibleTime = 1000;  //in milliseconds

        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.Show("Test ToolTip",TB,0,0,VisibleTime);
```

Play with X/Y values to move it where you want. Visible time is how long until it disappears.

Comment: Don't "play with X/Y values". Use the overload of `ToolTip.Show` that takes a control object and determines the correct position automatically.

Comment: Yes, but when the textbox is dithered, the control won't go there.